# Update a field annotated mappedBy

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Can i make a update in hibernate like this

```
    entityManager.createQuery("update test set  ... " +
            " where prop = :prop ")
            ....
            .setParameter("prop ", prop )
            .executeUpdate();
```

where `prop` is a field annotated by `mappedBy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a join to association to use it in the where clause. But Hibernate doesn't allow use joins with an update request. You should use a subquery. Please, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034327/using-a-join-in-a-hibernate-hql-update-query).

Comment: @Youssef You are welcome. If you want to see some interesting techniques using Hibernate see [this](https://www.livecoding.tv/ladynev/).